# Django rest_framework, disable authentication and permission in specific method

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a class called `UserViewSet` :

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserData.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
    from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)

    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False)
    def signup_user(self, request):
        request_data = request.query_params
        if len(request_data) == 0:
            return Response("Empty params !")
```

Now i want to signup a new user and it will raise this error :

> {
>       "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided." }

Its because of `Authentication` and `Permission` classes .

So whats the correct way to disable this classes in `signup` function ?

I used `authentication_classes` and `permission_classes` **decorators** but it has no effect on this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [action](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) decorator allows specifying action-specific permission classes. This should do:

```
    @action(methods=['post'], detail=False, permission_classes=[AllowAny])
    def signup_user(self, request):
        # ...
```

(don't forget importing [`AllowAny`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#allowany))

Comment: thanks , it solved the problem . can permission_classes be an empty list instead of AllowAny ?

Comment: Yes it can. An empty list has the same meaning as `[AllowAny]`. I like `[AllowAny]` because it makes the intent clearer (`[]` might look like you forgot the permission name; someone not familiar with DRF won't know the default policy without looking it up in the doc…).

Answer (score 1):

and for the default actions, i.e create , retrieve , update , partial_update , destroy and list, you can override the get_permissions method (for subclasses of rest mixins only)
i.e

```
def get_permissions(self):
    permission_classes = []
    if self.action =='create':
        permission_classes = [AllowAny,]
    else:
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]

    return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

at this point, you can even validate with the http methods, ie POST, GET, PUT ... by referencing `self.request`.

The same can be done to authentication_classes by overriding get_authenticators method

```
def get_authenticators(self):
    """
    Instantiates and returns the list of authenticators that this view can use.
    """
    authentication_classes = []
    if self.action !='create':
        authentication_classes = [TokenAuthentication, ]
    
    return [auth() for auth in authentication_classes]
```